# Hide elements with jQuery - let other elements slide to their new place?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've got a grid of items in different categories, and a some checkboxes which can disable certain categories. Right now they fade out, and then the other elements "jump" to their new place. Is there a plugin to let them slide somehow?

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
$('#hidefoo').click(function() {
    $('.foo').fadeToggle("fast");
});
});

<div class="griditem foo"></div>
<div class="griditem bar"></div>
<div class="griditem foo"></div>
<div class="griditem bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How is that http://jsfiddle.net/zUnHc/?

Comment: It's kind of what I want, but look at this fork: http://jsfiddle.net/wquZS/. The green and red one still jump to their new place, instead of sliding.

Comment: SlideToggle is fine if you only need to slide vertically. But if you want to slide horizontally then you need to use .animate() like in my answer.

Comment: @JCBK Isotope is just for you then: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ . Stack Exchange uses it too! http://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: Exactly what I need Ghokun, if this was an answer I'd accept it :).

Comment: No need for that since I just pointed you to a website. Glad I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$('.foo').animate({height:0});
```